# How to use React without unsafe inline JavaScript/CSS code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, content-security-policy, browser-extension

### Background

I have to use a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) for a react application.

The reason, that is however not of a big matter here, is, that I am creating a WebExtension/Browser Extension/add-on and these do have such a [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy), and there things like `'unsafe-eval'` and `'unsafe-inline'` are [strictly disallowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy#exampleNote_1):

> extensions with 'unsafe-eval', 'unsafe-inline', remote script, blob, or remote sources in their CSP are not allowed for extensions listed on addons.mozilla.org due to major security issues.

I have created the app with `create-react-app` loosly following [this guide](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2018/05/how-to-create-a-chrome-extension-in-react-js/).
The objective would be to be able to use react there [with the default CSP of WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#Default_content_security_policy), or, at least, only minor adjustments.

**However** note, that (such strict) CSPs should actually also be used on "normal" websites for security reasons, so this question is not *only* for  add-on makers.

### Problem

But when I run `npm run build` the generated `index.html` does contain more than enough [inline JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#Inline_JavaScript) code.

### Question

So how can I configure/use react to not do this and...

1. either instead put all JS/CSS code into seperate files?
2. or add nounces or something else that CSPs allow?
3. or solve that problem in a similar way?

### Edit

Actually, it seems the development version (created when I run `npm start`) does not have such minifications. So I've asked a seperate question for how to get the files from there: [How to build a production version of React without minification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165466/how-to-build-a-production-version-of-react-without-minification)

Comment: The only thing I can think is Webpack. Maybe you can configure it in the way you want.

Comment: @squeekyDave AFAIK the setup uses babel. Could not I configure it, too, in some way?

Comment: Babel its just a transpiler, what you want is module splitting I believe? So what I would do is build a baisc react app from scratch using webpack and play around to see if its possible to split the build files in the way you wanted.

Comment: I don't care at all whether it is in modules or so. (it can be one single JS file as react seems to create by default) It just should not be in the main HTML file with `script` tags or so...

Comment: @squeekyDave Also, if you think you have a working idea on how to do it with WebPack, feel free to submit it as an answer. :)

Comment: Also note: React actually already uses Webpack, so maybe I just need to get it to configure? ([Which seems to be hard enough...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55165586/5008962))

Comment: If you post something tha tyou have tried then I might be able to help, and not only me, everyone who see the question.

Comment: Thats why its better to start on a clean slate and build your dev server and react app from scratch.

Comment: I'll guess that is just an opinion... At least the official React docs make no mention of this "manual way". :)

Comment: Yes, of course, it's just my opinion. I believe that it will give you more insight on module splitting rather than trying to configure something already out of the box :)

Comment: That does lead to another question, however: How to configure it in such a way?

Comment: Okay, asked another follow-up question about this, @squeekyDave: [How to manually configure a minimal setup for React without create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166789/how-to-manually-configure-a-minimal-setup-for-react-without-create-react-app)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Actually [thanks to @heyimalex](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6643#issuecomment-473183280) I found a very easy answer for my problem. Just run the build script like this:

```
INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false npm run build
```

Afterwards, it should be CSP-compatible.

Comment: But, could someone throw some light on how this works? Does it affect the Lazy loading and load everything upfront?

Answer (score 51):

Anyone facing issue with `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false` with non recognized command in Windows system, below is the proper way to execute the command to prevent the inline chunk on the build.

`set "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false" && react-scripts build`

Create a script to execute it in your **package.json** file.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "set \"INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false\" && react-scripts build"
  }
```

I found that quotes around the **INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK** are necessary as well **&&** If the command is executed in Windows default command line.

For Linux, you can follow the accepted answer.

## Better way

Use the Environment variable so that you don't have to worry about running the command.

Create a **.env** file and add **INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false**.

Comment: Keep things nice and simple with https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env :)

For example:
"build": "cross-env INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false rescripts build && yarn tsc-electron",

Comment: thank buddy. putting quotes realy worked!

Answer (score 0):

Update your .env file `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false`.

Answer (score 0):

`INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false` is good but it is applicable for create-react-app. If you are using Webpack as an option you can use nonce, for example via `CspHtmlWebpackPlugin` and in webpack.config.js specify:

```
new CspHtmlWebpackPlugin(
    {
        'default-src': [
            "'self'"
        ],
        'script-src': ["'self'"],
        'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:'],
        'style-src': ["'self'"],
    },
    {
        enabled: true,
        nonceEnabled: {
            'style-src': true,
            'script-src': true,
        },
    }
),
```

It will generate automatically nonce hash for your styles and scripts..

If you have dynamic inline styles you can also use nonce via this plugin:
in your entry point of html just specify:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="%%CSP_CONTENT%%">
```

and in your webpack just add to `style-src`:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'process.env.NONCE_GENERATED': JSON.stringify(nonceGenerated),
}),
new CspHtmlWebpackPlugin(
{
   'default-src': [
        "'self'"
    ],
        'script-src': ["'self'"],
        'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:'],
        'style-src': ["'self'", `'nonce-${nonceGenerated}'`],
},
{
    enabled: true,
    nonceEnabled: {
        'style-src': true,
        'script-src': true,
    },
}),
```

and in JS use it and add to the tag:

```
const generatedNonce= process.env.NONCE_GENERATED;
```