# Safe CSP with React inline chunk

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy, webpack-style-loader, inline-styles

I would like to have the safest possible setup for my React front-end. Currently I run `server.js` out of the `/build` folder in deployment, so it is in a compiled, production state.

However, I can't use the following CSP which is fairly restrictive, if the js is bundled and inlined:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=
  "default-src 'none'; 
   object-src 'self'; 
   script-src 'self'; 
   worker-src 'self'; 
   connect-src 'self'; 
   img-src 'self' data:; 
   style-src 'self'; 
   font-src 'self'; 
   manifest-src 'self';">
```

I also get

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'".
```

Since some node_modules like Draggable seem to dynamically inline styles.

What is an approach for me so that I can keep my code fairly obfuscated to deter attackers as well as a strong CSP? I've heard a webpack plugin might help but I don't really understand how that works in the build pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I resolved this by changing from true to false the INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK value in `.env`. There is a little more info in this answer: [How to use React without unsafe inline JavaScript/CSS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160698/how-to-use-react-without-unsafe-inline-javascript-css-code)

Also consider breaking up into `.env.development` and `.env.production`: [What is the difference between .env.local and .env.development.local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690143/what-is-the-difference-between-env-local-and-env-development-local)

Comment: So you dont get any <styles> ... any more? I tried using INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK and it seems to work with scripts but not with styles =/ any clue?

Comment: @Flezcano No the stylesheets are still an issue unfortunately. It looks like based on Carlos' answer it really has to be done server-side somehow.

Comment: Do you know if there is any offical documentation about this limitation?

Comment: @Flezcano Not that I know of. Of course it's possible I still have CSS somewhere inline...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach too https://cssinjs.org/csp/?v=v10.8.2. Implement a ExpressJs server that generates the headers and inject them into the react application. Keep in mind that many libraries already come with csp support and you must apply the generated nonce.